# Зачем надо ключевое слово PUBLIC в target_sources()?

Tags: cmake

Зачем надо ключевое слово PUBLIC в target_sources()?

Answer (score 1):

[Официальная документация](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) не помогает? Публичные файлы реализации будут добавлены к переменной [`INTERFACE_SOURCES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_SOURCES.html) для этой цели. В дальнейшем, при импортировании данной цели, данная переменная может быть использована для извлечения файлов реализации. Из документации выше видно, что подобное извлечение характерно для `target_link_libraries`, т.е. эта информация используется ей для «встраивания» зависимостей.

Лично я не встречал подобного использования и особого смысла в нём не вижу. Если нужно экспортировать свой код, то лучше создавать библиотеку.